# Recursive method for adding 0 after every odd digit of an integer

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to figure it out how to make an recursive method for adding 0 after every odd digit of an integer.
Ths is what i have so far

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digit a positive int number: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();


    }


    public static int addingZeroToOddDigit(int number) {
    if (number==0) {
        return 0;
    }else{
       if(number&1){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a "recursive method" ? Your code snippet don't seem to be one. Plus your code seem really incomplete, it's hard to work with the code that you provide. To improve your chances of getting an answer I suggest that you take a look at [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek and make your question less likely to get down voted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the remaining of a number n order to know if it is odd or even.

```
  public static int addingZeroToOddDigit(int number) {
    if (number%2==0) {
      //Even number
      return number;
    } else {
      //Odd number
      return number*10;
    }
  }
```

And then multiply by ten as you are manipulating integers. But of course if it is supposed to be a recursive function, every time you add a zero the number stays being an even number, so you will have an endless loop.